# can't align strings on my bill properly

Tags: mysql, vb.net

This is my code

```vb
Public Sub ItemsToBePrinted()
    Try
        dbcon = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;User Id=root; password=hello; Database=demo;")
        strQuery = "select * from bill where customerid= '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbcon)
        dbcon.Open()
        nDR = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader
        TextToPrint &= "Itemname" & "     " & "Quantity" & "" & " Price" & "" & " Total" & Environment.NewLine
        If nDR.HasRows Then
            Do While nDR.Read
                Dim StringToPrint1 As String = nDR.GetString(2) & ""
                Dim StringToPrint2 As String = nDR.GetString(1) & ""
                Dim StringToPrint3 As String = nDR.GetDouble(3) & ""
                Dim StringToPrint4 As String = nDR.GetDouble(4) & ""
                '& "  " & nDR.GetString(1) & "      " & nDR.GetDouble(3) & "  " & nDR.GetDouble(4)
                '  StringToPrint = String.Format("{0,-10}{1,-10}{2,-10}{3,-10}", nDR.GetString(2), nDR.GetString(1), nDR.GetDouble(3), nDR.GetDouble(4))
                Dim LineLen1 As String = StringToPrint1.Length
                Dim LineLen2 As String = StringToPrint1.Length
                Dim LineLen3 As String = StringToPrint1.Length
                Dim LineLen4 As String = StringToPrint1.Length
                Dim spcLen5 As New String(" "c, Math.Round((50 - LineLen1)))

                TextToPrint &= StringToPrint1 & " " 'Environment.NewLine
                TextToPrint &= StringToPrint2 & " " 'Environment.NewLine
                TextToPrint &= StringToPrint3 & " " 'Environment.NewLine
                TextToPrint &= StringToPrint4 & Environment.NewLine
            Loop
            nDR.NextResult()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I want to display all the strings in table format. The output of this is in this format

```
itemname | qty | price | total
coffee   |  2  |   20  | 40
tea      |  2  |   10  | 20
                 Total | 60
```

Comment: Is this VBScript or VB? It's definitely not C#, which is why I've removed the C# tag... please only use relevant tags.

Comment: It's not VBScript either.

Comment: Use a fixed-size font like Consolas.